# not being responsive on css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide the section called trending podcast and trying to show section slider when it is smaller or equal to 990px .The trending podcast section is hidden successfully but slider section is not visible
This is my css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px)
{
     #sliders
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #trending-podcast
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This is my html

```
    <section id="sliders">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active custom-slider">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Breaking Tricks</h5>
            <p>Reading Tricks</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item custom-slider">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Breaking Tricks</h5>
            <p>Reading Tricks</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item custom-slider">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
             <h5>Breaking Tricks</h5>
            <p>Reading Tricks</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="trending-podcast">
    <div class="container">
        <h4 class="trending-podcast-title">Trending Podcast</h4>
        <a href="" class="view-all-podcast">View All</a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 img-box-responsive">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
                      <img src="images/readingclub.jpg" alt="..." class="border-img">
                      <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
                        <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
                        <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
                      <img src="images/readingclub.jpg" alt="..." class="border-img">
                      <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
                        <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
                        <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
                      <img src="images/readingclub.jpg" alt="..." class="border-img">
                      <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
                        <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
                        <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
                      <img src="images/readingclub.jpg" alt="..." class="border-img">
                      <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
                        <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
                        <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What i am trying to do is when window size is normal the slider section should be remain hidden and podcast part should be visible but when it reduces to more than or equal to 990px the podcast part should be hidden and the slider part should be visible .
In small screen it is hidding the podcast part but not showing the slider section

Comment: It is conceivable that there is some other interfering css or JavaScript, etc.  If you could post a working demo, or public link to the issue, it would be easier.  Else, I suggesting using Dev Tools to inspect the hidden section...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you put the media query before

```
#sliders{
   display : none;
}
#trending-podcast{
   display : block;
}
```

the browser read the css top to bottom and if it find the same selector it will take the property from the last one.
click on "Run this snippet" then on "full page" and open console. then switch between desktop and mobile view.

```css
#sliders{
   display : none;
}
#trending-podcast{
   display : block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  #sliders {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #trending-podcast {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
<section id="sliders">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active custom-slider">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Breaking Tricks</h5>
          <p>Reading Tricks</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item custom-slider">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Breaking Tricks</h5>
          <p>Reading Tricks</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item custom-slider">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Breaking Tricks</h5>
          <p>Reading Tricks</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="trending-podcast">
  <div class="container">
    <h4 class="trending-podcast-title">Trending Podcast</h4>
    <a href="" class="view-all-podcast">View All</a>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 img-box-responsive">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="..." class="border-img">
            <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
              <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
              <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="..." class="border-img">
            <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
              <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
              <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="..." class="border-img">
            <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
              <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
              <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="" class="thumbnail-a">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" alt="..." class="border-img">
            <div class="caption" class="reading-tricks">
              <h4>Reading Tricks</h4>
              <p class="color-ccc">Breaking Tricks</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

As reading your question it seems that on desktop size you want to show `trending podcast` and hide slider section but when screen will reach at `990px` so you want to show `slider` section but want to hide `trending podcast` section. So you have to put display block in normal desktop size css above all media queries like this

```
#sliders{
   display : none;
}
#trending-podcast{
   display : block;
}
```

but for less than `990px` screens you should do like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px)
 {
   #sliders{
    display: block !important;
   }
   #trending-podcast{
    display: none !important;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I would be hesitant about splashing `!important`s around until I understood the underlying cause

Comment: we use `!important` when we want to override css of any element.  Just try my solution and let me know if it's working or not?  For more info about `!important` you can have a look at this article

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/

Comment: If only there was `!importanter` and `!omgz-super-importantest` then you'd be fine ;)